# django makemigrations Failing When Trying to Add ForeignKey to Existing Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, makemigrations

I have a model, and I'm trying to add a foreignkey field to it.

This is the field definition:

```
part_of_speech = models.ForeignKey('PartOfSpeech', help_text=_('Translation | part_of_speech | help_text'), verbose_name = _('Translation','part_of_speech'))
```

When I try to perform the `makemigrations` command, I get the following error:

```
Migrations for 'dictionary':
  0024_translation_part_of_speech.py:
    - Add field part_of_speech to translation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 143, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 171, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 146, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 104, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 74, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(_arg_value)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 354, in serialize
    return cls.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 248, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = cls.serialize(arg)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 276, in serialize
    value = force_text(value)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 92, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 141, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
TypeError: ugettext() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `null=True` and `blank=True`?

Comment: Yes. I have. I get the same error in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help text declaration (the call to ugetttext) is formatted improperly. To solve this, change this:

```
verbose_name = _('Translation','part_of_speech')
```

to this:

```
verbose_name = _('Translation | part_of_speech')
```